# Solve the current theough 15Ω load resistance using Norton's theorem

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, short-circuit, norton, resistance-measurement

[image]

Here, I am asked to find out the current through the 15 ohm load resistor (the resistor on the extreme right) using Norton's theorem. I have proceeded with the sum and found out the Norton's equivalent resistant to be 5 ohms.

Now, I was proceeding to find the norton's short circuit current when i found out:-

I had removed the 15 ohm load resistor and short circuited its path. So, when the current comes out from the 10V source, it doesn't enter the two 20 ohm resistor paths (since the paths have a greater resistance) but instead flows directly through the short circuited load resistance path.

My question is- to find out the current through the short circuited path, I am to use the formula i=V/R. I know that V is 10V. But, I can't understand what I should take the R to be? Will it be the Nortons Equivalent Resistance(=5 ohm) or the actual equivakent resistance accross the 10V source(=16 ohms)? Or am I conceptually wrong somewhere?

[image]

Comment: It might be better to show a schematic of your reductions, and also label your components. Note the 15 ohm reisstor is driven by a 'source' with output resistance 5 ohms and voltage 5 volts. Do your sums on how that source drives the 15 ohm resistor.

Comment: Sure. I am including them

Comment: @Neil_UK done what you asked for :) PS: forgive me for my beautiful handwriting

Comment: Right, in the short circuit mode, the 20's are in parallel with 0, so 10V is applied to 10 ohms. These are two separate steps, don't worry about R_N for this step.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks